# Consulta PHP Codeigniter + mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Sou novo aqui no fórum e gostaria de uma ajuda com um probleminha que já me consumiu algumas horas. Acredito que pode ser algum detalhe que não estou conseguindo visualizar..

Problema: Basicamente preciso de algumas informações pra montar um relatório, no *MySQL Workbench* consigo exatamente o que quero, porém na hora de "traduzir" a query para o códio não consigo o mesmo resultado (na vdd, não me retorna nada). A linguagem de programação é PHP no CodeIgniter.

**No Workbench:**

```
select tec_payments.sale_id, tec_payments.paid_by as pagamento, 
tec_payments.date, tec_payments.amount, tec_sale_items.product_id, 
tec_sale_items.category_id  
from tec_payments
left join tec_sale_items on tec_sale_items.sale_id = tec_payments.sale_id
where tec_payments.date between '2019-07-03 00:00:00' and '2019-07-03 00:00:00'
and tec_sale_items.category_id = 14
and tec_payments.paid_by = 'cash';
```

**Resultado da Consulta:**

```
sale_id | pagamento | date              |  amount     | product_id | category_id
   1        cash    2019-07-03 00:00:00 |   18.00        83           14
   1        cash    2019-07-03 00:00:00 |   18.00        83           14
   2        cash    2019-07-03 00:00:00 |   145.00       94           14
   2        cash    2019-07-03 00:00:00 |   145.00       95           14
   6        cash    2019-07-03 00:00:00 |   37.00        66           14
   6        cash    2019-07-03 00:00:00 |   37.00        43           14
   7        cash    2019-07-03 00:00:00 |   17.00        76           14
```

No método preciso passar alguns parâmetros, mas o meu model está recebendo tudo certo. Enfim, é isso! 
Desde já, muito obrigado galera!

Como me foi sugerido, aqui está o código em PHP (Esse é o model):

```
public function getItensDate($categoria = null, $start_date = null, $end_date = null) {

        $pagamento = 'cash';
        $whereCategoria = "";
        $whereData = "";
        $wherePagamento = "AND payments.paid_by = " . $pagamento;

        if ($start_date != null) {
        $whereData = "WHERE payments.date BETWEEN " . $this->db->escape($start_date) . " AND " . $this->db->escape($end_date);
        }
        if ($categoria != null) {
        $whereCategoria = "AND sale_items.category_id = " . $categoria;
        }

        $query =  "SELECT payments.sale_id, payments.paid_by as pagamento, payments.date, payments.amount, sale_items.product_id, sale_items.category_id 
                  FROM payments
                  LEFT JOIN sale_items ON sale_items.sale_id = payments.sale_id
                  $whereData $whereCategoria $wherePagamento";

        //print_r($query);
        //exit;

        return $this->db->query($query)->result();

    }
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo a comunidade @Italo! Para facilitar na interpretação e na resposta de seu problema, sugiro que retire as imagens e copie o seu código aqui mesmo. O editor de texto tem a funcionalidade de formatar o código através do botão **{ }**. Caso este procedimento seja complicado para você, adicione o código sem formatação que a galera da comunidade consegue arrumar pra você.

Comment: Oi, @VictorCarnaval fiz a alteração. Obrigado pela dica!

Comment: faça isso também para a consulta e para o resultado da consulta, removendo as imagens e deixando apenas texto.

Comment: Só não consegui muito bem com o resultado da consulta.

Comment: Aceita a edição que eu arrumei pra você :)

Comment: Pronto, Valeu!!

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
public function getItensDate($categoria = null, $start_date = null, $end_date = null)
{

    $query = $this->db;
    $where = array();

    $query->select('payments.sale_id, payments.paid_by as pagamento, payments.date, payments.amount, sale_items.product_id, sale_items.category_id')
        ->from('payments')
        ->join('sale_items', 'sale_items.sale_id = payments.sale_id', 'left');

    if ($start_date && $end_date) {
        $where[] = "payments.date BETWEEN " . $query->escape($start_date) . " AND " . $query->escape($end_date);
    }
    if ($categoria) {
        $where[] = "sale_items.category_id = $categoria";
    }

    if (!empty($where)) {
        $whereRaw = implode(' AND ', $where);
        $query->where($whereRaw);
    }

    return $query->get()->result();    
}
```